# How can I delete the reminders database?

Tags: applications, reminders

seems my reminders data are corrupted. A regular task is popping up again and again which I cannot delete (error message).

I am fine with deleting ALL regular tasks from both the reminders and calendar app.

Is there a safe way to empty reminders recurrent entries (or, delete the reminders data completely without loosing non-reminder entries in calendar? I am aware both are nastily intertwined.

(MBP 2015 Mojave 10.14.1)

Comment: Goog search found the following: https://appletoolbox.com/2018/02/reminders-app-shows-incorrect-information-how-to-fix/  Note - I've not tried this. Good luck.

Comment: No, enabling the debug menu in reminders.app and doing a refresh did not help, alas.

Comment: I also tried using AppCleaner. I tried to delete all associated files from reminders.app but not the app itself. AppCleaner did not do the job completely, so I had to delete a few files from the terminal with sudo. Yet, those bad repetitive tasks are still there ! Mind boggling. I am close to trashing the reminders.app and looking for a better alternative...

Comment: Yeah - aggravating, I've been there. If you have AppleCare, you might try them? I like Apple & MacOS; I can't imagine going back to Windows. But I have to say this: when something breaks on my MacBook, it's occasionally a HUGE PAIN to fix. This due mostly to the odd (by my reckoning) things they do... like "sparse bundles" for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are Reminders stored on disk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245576/where-are-reminders-stored-on-disk)