# How to resolve Reminders keeps crashing when accessing "ToDo" folder

Tags: macos, high-sierra, crash, reminders

I'm using 10.13.6 macOS High Sierra. Reminders keeps crashing when I try to access a personally-made folder called "ToDo" I'm not sure if that folder name is reserved for the system, but it was working for quite a while. Regardless, I wish to purge some cache or something that will preserve my information and allow me to access my personally-made ToDo folder on Reminders. I've pulled up this SE post,

[Where are Reminders stored on disk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245576/where-are-reminders-stored-on-disk)

which has been helpful as I can see the .ics files with content, so the data is there, but I'm thinking I need to delete some cache file to move on.

Here's a redacted and abbreviated crash report, hopefully showing the pertinent data:

```
Process:               Reminders [2414]
Path:                  /Applications/Reminders.app/Contents/MacOS/Reminders
Identifier:            com.apple.reminders
Version:               5.0 (1457.4.1)
Build Info:            Reminders-1457004001000000~508
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Reminders [2414]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-03-24 15:05:19.543 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G14042)
Report Version:        12

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
Crashing on exception: NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:: nil value

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4e571f3b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff75a26942 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4e6022d5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff5062c0da -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:] + 149
4   CalendarUI                          0x00007fff5fc9ccff -[NSAttributedString(CalClassAdditions) stringWithRange:formattedWithURL:withColor:andUnderline:] + 233
5   CalendarUI                          0x00007fff5fc9c436 -[NSAttributedString(CalClassAdditions) stringWithOneURLFormattedAsAppSpecificHyperlinkWithColor:andUnderline:] + 708
6   CalendarUI                          0x00007fff5fc9c108 -[NSAttributedString(CalClassAdditions) stringWithURLsFormattedAsAppSpecificHyperlinksWithColor:andUnderline:] + 54
7   Reminders                           0x0000000106640d43 Reminders + 113987
8   Reminders                           0x0000000106640b78 Reminders + 113528
9   Reminders                           0x000000010664089c Reminders + 112796
10  Reminders                           0x000000010663fba3 Reminders + 109475
11  Reminders                           0x000000010663d420 Reminders + 99360
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bc0679b -[NSTableView(NSTableViewViewBased) _delegate_viewForTableColumn:row:] + 86
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb80ec4 -[NSTableView(NSTableViewViewBased) makeViewForTableColumn:row:] + 87
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb80747 -[NSTableRowData _addViewToRowView:atColumn:row:] + 342
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb80421 -[NSTableRowData _addViewsToRowView:atRow:] + 211
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb7eaa4 -[NSTableRowData _initializeRowView:atRow:] + 397
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c46a96a -[NSTableRowData _preparedRowViewForRow:storageHandler:] + 154
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb7ced1 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] + 392
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb7cc94 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorRowIndex:inDictionary:withRowAnimation:] + 416
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c46cae9 -[NSTableRowData _updateVisibleRowEntries] + 1720
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb7b992 -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] + 294
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb7b163 -[NSTableView layout] + 206
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c324ad0 _NSViewLayout + 587
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1eeff -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 437
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb1f178 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 1070
36  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c32b82c -[NSView _layoutSubtreeIfNeededAndAllowTemporaryEngine:] + 1380
37  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bb3c6ef -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutViewTree] + 163
38  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bba7e83 -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) layoutIfNeeded] + 268
39  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c359443 ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke.5896 + 67
40  AppKit                              0x00007fff4bbb855e __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke + 695
41  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff5989a877 _ZN2CA11Transaction19run_commit_handlersE18CATransactionPhase + 49
42  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff59899339 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 171
43  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c370a72 __65+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayRefresh]_block_invoke + 283
44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4e50a507 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4e50a42f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 511
46  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4e4ecef8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1240
47  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4e4ec787 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
48  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff4d7ccd96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
49  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff4d7ccb06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
50  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff4d7cc884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
51  AppKit                              0x00007fff4ba79a3b _DPSNextEvent + 2085
52  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c20fe34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
53  AppKit                              0x00007fff4ba6e84d -[NSApplication run] + 764
54  AppKit                              0x00007fff4ba3da3a NSApplicationMain + 804
55  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff76641015 start + 1
56  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4bda4454 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 109
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4c370cb1 __65+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayRefresh]_block_invoke + 858
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e50a507 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e50a42f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 511
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4ecef8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1240
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4ec787 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4d7ccd96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4d7ccb06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4d7cc884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4ba79a3b _DPSNextEvent + 2085
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4c20fe34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4ba6e84d -[NSApplication run] + 764
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4ba3da3a NSApplicationMain + 804
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff76641015 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7695920e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76959009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7695920e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76959009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76959009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76959009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76959009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7679228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7695920e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff767881fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff76787714 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4eddc5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4ed117 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4ec787 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4bbb6fc4 _NSEventThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76959661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7695950d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: NetworkLoad
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff767881fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff76787714 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4eddc5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4ed117 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4e4ec787 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.apple.GeoServices           0x00007fff673e6d1a _runNetworkThread + 480
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76959661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7695950d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff76958bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fdbc68d9800  rbx: 0x000060c00044e1c0  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x00000000000017be
  rdi: 0x0000000008000101  rsi: 0x00007fdbc691bd91  rbp: 0x00007ffee95d92d0  rsp: 0x00007ffee95d92c0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007ffee95d8dc8  r11: 0xfffffffffffbf1ff
  r12: 0x000060c0001340a0  r13: 0x00007fdbc680c060  r14: 0x00007fff75a18e80  r15: 0x00007fff4e50a7b0
  rip: 0x00007fff4bda4454  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000060c0002d8000
  
Logical CPU:     6
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6
```

Comment: Can you upload a crash report? Should be found in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`.

Comment: I haven’t looked through a crash report yet, but how sterilized are they with personal data? Good idea though, even if I must redact some areas

Comment: Added part of crash report in an edit to original post. Hopefully you can see something. Maybe I can merely hack an .ics file to make it work again?  I still think deleting some cache might be harmless and let me work again, but which one?

Comment: Just try renaming the folder to something else (e.g. ToDoo) just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

With an Apple ID, you can (or could have) save your reminders in iCloud. "Continuity" allows you to then access your "ToDo" content on other Apple devices that has the same Apple ID signed in on. If your Mac is the only Apple device you have, and that the reminders are stored in the cloud, you can still head to [Reminders](https://www.icloud.com/reminders/) web app to rescue your reminders.

Comment: This is only applicable for 10.15 Catalina and beyond. While my iPhone has the latest software, my MBP does not. As a result, my reminders on both could not be synchronized because it would break the database on the MBP with 10.13.6 High Sierra. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210220

Comment: @bento I suggest that you update your macOS to the latest supported version to use these synchronization features, unless your Mac is too old to do so, which then there is no other solutions I can think of other than suggesting you to get a new Mac, especially if a broken "ToDo" folder can interfere with your work or affect your productivity

Comment: This MBP cannot be upgraded further. Reminders was working, and I see my data as I explained in .ics files. I just don’t know what Reminders is loading to create a crash. Alleviating that issue would allow it to succeed in loading. After this, I’ll abandon using it on the MBP.

Comment: Actually, now that I thought about it, I know about a way to let Mac display logs from apps. Enter `/System/Applications/Reminders.app/Contents/MacOS/Reminders` in your Terminal App to execute the binary in Reminders app and start the app. Watch the log outputs in the Terminal while you navigate to "ToDo" folder. If there are any errors theoretically you can see from the Terminal window and maybe get some clues from it. I used this method to troubleshoot various different apps in the past and should work for you too.

Comment: Not sure it’ll give more than I already have from the crash log, but I will certainly give it a shot. EDIT: part of crash log was added in an edit previously to the original post.