# How can I import reminders from *.ics files to Monterey's Reminders app?

Tags: macos, monterey, migration, reminders

I am migrating from an old mac running macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra to a new mac running macOS 12.3.1 Monterey. I am having difficulty migrating my Reminders items manually to the Reminders app on Monterey.

I am migrating manually and selectively, because I want to leave behind accumulated cruft from past systems. Thus I don't use Migration Assistant. Also, I do not use iCloud and would rather not start now.

I have exported each of my Reminders lists to *.ics files from the High Sierra Reminders app, and copied the files to the new mac. The Reminders app on Monterey, which apparently got a makeover since the previous macOS version, has no menu items to "import" or "open" files with reminder items.

How can I import my reminders to the Reminders app on macOS 12.3.1 Monterey?

A related subsidiary question: where does the Reminders app store its data on Monterey and later?

I called Apple support with this question. Their answer: the only ways to transfer reminder items are via iCloud or via Migration Assistant. Maybe that truly is the answer to this question, but I am hopeful that the clever folks here will have better ideas.

There is a related question, [Where are Reminders stored on disk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/245576/17600). That is about MacOS X 10.11 El Capitan, and I believe the answer is different for Monterey.