# How to restore deleted list on Reminders on MacOS?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, reminders

I accidentally deleted Reminders list on Reminders app on MacOS (MacBook Air). The list was synced with the Reminders list on Reminders app on my iPhone. The list is still there on the iPhone. How can I get this back again to the Reminders app on my MacBook Air?

I also created a new list on MacBook Air and a new list on iPhone. They both don't appear on other devices.

Comment: The first thing, after any erroneous move is to Undo [Cmd/z, or on a phone, shake the device]. This may still work if you haven't tried too many new things already to try fix it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oops! It's too late. I wish I had done that!

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245576/where-are-reminders-stored-on-disk for the location & see if Time Machine has it